# change font size latex "res" class

Tags: fontsize, cv, resume

I am using res.cls by Michael DeCorte to create my CV. I wanted to increase the font size.

```
\documentclass[resmargin]{res}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: FYI: The class mentioned is quite old, there are much more modern classes and packages for CVs.

Comment: res.cls load articls.cls so nothing special for font size

Comment: By 'nothing special' touhami may mean adding `11pt` or `12pt` to the class options, e.g. `\documentclass[resmargin,12pt]{res}`.

Comment: @Torbjon T, Thank you very much for your answer. It works good..

Answer (score 2):

As touhami says, `res.cls` loads `article`, and it doesn't change the default size of `10pt`. Hence, you can add either `11pt` or `12pt` to the class options to get a larger font, e.g.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{res}
```

This is also mentioned in the comments at the start of `res.cls`, where you'll find

```
% You can have multiple style options the legal options ones are:
%
%  [some other options]
%       
%   11pt    use 11 point fonts instead of 10 point fonts
%
%   12pt    use 12 point fonts instead of 10 point fonts
```